# Xeon Processors and large transactions

Tags: xeon

A little background:

We have a windows service which gets data from an external server and stores them on a local DB (SQL server 2012).

The external server sends more than 1500 “messages” per second, but our storage rate is almost 500 msg/s for the local server ( the windows service and database are on a single VM with Xeon E5520 and 16 GBs of RAM on a HP G7 Server/ windows server 2012).

When I move the service and DB to my local PC, the storage rate rises to 1100 msg/s.

I did the test on multiple PCs (core2 duo and core i5) and Servers (HP G7 and G8, VM and physical servers), the result was the same:  all PCs get messages in a way better rate than our servers.

We thought It might be a network problem, but it was not.

I did a “Memory Transaction Throughput” test with “Sisoft Sandra” on Servers and PCs and figured out that our PCs do a much better job than the servers . the **minimum** PC result was 5.4MTPS (on a core2 duo E7400), the **maximum** server result was 3MTPS  (on a HP Proliant DL380P with Xeon E5-2650).

I tend to conclude that there’s something wrong with Xeon processors, but that would be a strange conclusion since there are dozens of Xeon DB Servers around the world.

Am I missing something? Is there a special configuration on the BIOS to solve this problem?

Comment: You could try some tuning. What are the clock speeds of the various processors involved? Are your A/B tests using the same switching infrastructure? Have you made *any* BIOS changes to the server?

Comment: @ewwhite thanks for the reply and comment. as I wrote in the question I did the test on different processors (with different clock speeds) but the infrastructure was (almost) the same. haven't change any thing in BIOS yet.

Comment: Try the low-hanging fruit first... enable the "Maximum Performance" profile in the HP ProLiant BIOS.

Comment: Literally *DOZENS!!*

Comment: How fast is the RAM?

Comment: I changed the Power profile to “Maximum Performance”  -on a physical HP server (2*Xeon E2650 2GHz, 32 cores, 64GB Ram (1066 MHz)- and performance increased by almost 20%. It’s still slower than my Core2 duo (2.8 Ghz) PC with 4 GB (800 MHz) Ram!

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a messaging application, and you're using HP ProLiant servers, I'd treat this as a low-latency configuration... If this is a easily-reproducible test, can you try the following?

- Update your server firmware. Make sure the system BIOS and NICs are on current firmware. If you use the [HP Service Pack for ProLiant bootable DVD](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx), it will handle all of the relevant components.
- Set your ProLiant servers to the "Maximum Performance" power profile. This will disable the processor C-states and may be helpful for what you're doing.
- Prefer the bare-metal solution if it makes more sense logistically. Virtualized networking always carries some overhead.

Look at some of the [tuning recommendations](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01804533.pdf) we use for messaging-heavy applications.